# How to check if Python list contains an index (negative values include)

Tags: python

Is there build-in way to define is Python list contain some index, negative value include.

I mean function like:

```
x in [M1, ..., Mn]
```

but for index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positive indices will run from `0` to `len(seq) - 1`.

Negative indices will run from `-1` to `-len(seq)`.

Comment: I mean function like:

    x in [n, m]

Answer (score 1):

Python will throw an `IndexError` if the specified index doesn't exist. Simply do:

```
def contains_index(l, index):
    try:
        temp = l[index]
        return True
    except IndexError:
        return False
```